# Why is the output of this find -newermt command apparently not in order?

Tags: command-line, files, ext4, find

When I run

```
touch a.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
touch b.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
touch c.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
touch d.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
touch e.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
touch f.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
find -newermt "1 sec ago"
```

the listing doesn't seem to be in order.

```
$ touch a.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> touch b.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> touch c.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> touch d.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> touch e.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> touch f.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> find -newermt "1 sec ago"
./d.txt
./f.txt
./a.txt
./c.txt
./b.txt
./e.txt
$
```

The order is reproducible. But why is the order the way it is? I know I can sort the output but the order of the default output just seems odd.

By the way, the same order is generated if `-printf '%T@ %p\n'` is used:

```
$ touch a.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> touch b.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> touch c.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> touch d.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> touch e.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> touch f.txt && sleep 0.1 && \
> find -newermt "1 sec ago" -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n'
1567346420.7185077410 ./d.txt
1567346420.9305093600 ./f.txt
1567346420.3905052190 ./a.txt
1567346420.6065068740 ./c.txt
1567346420.5025060780 ./b.txt
1567346420.8225085330 ./e.txt
$
```

---

```
$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     785M  1.7M  784M   1% /run
/dev/sda6      ext4      288G   99G  175G  37% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G   39M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1      vfat      496M   39M  458M   8% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     785M     0  785M   0% /run/user/118
tmpfs          tmpfs     785M   28K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
$
```

The filesystem is the default, *ext4*.

---

The shell from which these commands were run is `bash`:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: They are returned in the order provided by the glibc `readdir()` function I think (which may in turn depend on the filesystem on which the files reside). Further reading: [Does readdir() guarantee an order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977441/does-readdir-guarantee-an-order)

Comment: Yes, the filesystem is *ext4*, which according to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977441/does-readdir-guarantee-an-order#comment11247056_8977441) in your link specifically mentions *ext4* as not following any particular order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two important concepts here: `-newerXY` only affects which files are operated on and not the order in which they are operated on, the the order `find` discovers *siblings* is unspecified and in practice contingent on the implementation details of the filesystem driver.

### `-newerXY` filters but it does not sort.

The `-newermt` predicate tests if files were modified more recently than the time you specify as its operand (`1 sec ago` in this case), filtering out those that are older. It does not affect the order in which `find` discovers files, nor does it affect the order in which actions (including the default `-print` action when no other action is supplied) are performed, which is the same as the order in which files are discovered. Since `find` performs actions on files in the order they are discovered and does not sort its output, `newermt` does not cause files to be sorted by their modification time.

All this applies equally to other forms of `-newerXY`.

### Files in the same directory may be discovered in any order.

As for what the order of discovery is, as [steeldriver says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170000/why-is-the-output-of-this-find-newermt-command-apparently-not-in-order#comment1952504_1170000), there is no guaranteed order for this **for files residing directly in the same directory**. You may sometimes see files in the same order in similar situations and sometimes not, and there is no promise made about the order.

`find` operates recursively, walking the entire directory hierarchy from each of its starting points. (Ubuntu uses GNU find which treats the absence of a specified starting point, as in your example, as meaning to start from `.`.) Specifically, it performs a depth-first preorder traversal of one or more directory trees. It is possible to limit where in a tree it goes with the `-maxdepth` and `-prune` predicates, as well as to prevent it from selecting files based on where they are in the tree in various ways (including `-mindepth`), but otherwise it looks everywhere under its starting points.

This *does* imply some constraints on the order in which it discovers files. It cannot skip back and forth between files in different directories. If you give it `a` as a starting point, it may discover `a/x/1` before or after `a/x/2`. If it finds `a/y`, it may appear either before or after `a/x/y` and `a/x/2`. This is all to say that entries residing immediately in the same directory may be processed in any order. But `a/y` will not appear *between* `a/x/1` and `a/x/2`.

Comment: • I get the same order using `find -mmin -1` of course with some additional interspersed entries. • All the touched files are in the same directory. • I also ran the same code from a folder which had no lower subfolders, ~/Public: same order.

Comment: I also tried from ~/Videos: exactly the same order. So there seems to be some method in the madness?

Comment: @DKBose Yes, the order is unspecified, not random. It depends on the data structures used by the filesystem and the implementation details of the filesystem driver, and you cannot rely on it even for separate traversals of the same files, but it is not surprising that it's sometimes stable and that it follows or appears to follow a discernible pattern.

Comment: Yes, and as steeldriver's link suggests, it's better to sort the output in any case.